# Hortonworks Practice Exam - Copy File from local machine to hdfs ERROR

Tags: hadoop, sudo, hortonworks-data-platform

I am currently working on the Hortonworks practice exam and I am getting errors I have not been able to troubleshoot.

During the first step the prompt asks `Put the three files from the home/horton/datasets/flight delays directory on the local machine into the user/horton/flight delays directory in hdfs permission denied error`. When on the node that hdfs is installed on (root@namenode). I run the simple command:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/horton/datasets/flightdelays/flight_delays1.csv /user/horton/flightdelays
```

This returns the error `/home/horton/datasets/flightdelays/flight_delays1.csv no such file or directory`

When I run the same exact command above from the command line on the local machine instead of running it after being ssh'd onto the namenode (horton@some-ip) I get a permission denied error:

`permission denied user=horton access=WRITE inode='/user/horton/flightdelays":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x`

If anyone has done this practice exam before or knows what this error is and could lend any assistance it would be greatly appreciated. When researching online a lot of people are running into the same issue with the permission denied but im going to assume that on a practice exam that they set up you shouldn't be needing to use sudo for every command you run.

Again any help would be fantastic thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this on CLI

`sudo -u hdfs hdfs -copyFromLocal /input/file/path /hdfs/path/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your command line

```
hadoop fs -put /localfile.txt /hdfs path
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the folder you're trying to write to has ownership and permssions of `hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x` meaning it is owned by the 'hdfs' user and group. Only the hdfs user has write permissions to that folder everyone else has read and execute permissions only. Thus writing to that folder as the 'horton' user will not work.

You need to run the command as hdfs like so:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/horton/datasets/flightdelays/flight_delays1.csv /user/horton/flightdelays
```